# How to map to multiple objects within one Observable array?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular2-observables

I am using forkJoin to join two observable arrays together:

```
connect(): Observable<any[]> {
this.userId = this.authService.userId;
this.habits$ = this.habitService.fetchAllById(this.userId);
this.status$ = this.statusService.fetchAll();
this.joined$ = forkJoin([this.habits$, this.status$]).pipe(
  map(([habits, statuses]) =>
    habits.map(habit => ({
      ...habit,
      status: statuses.find(s => s.habitId === habit.habitId)
    })))
);
console.log(this.joined$);

return this.joined$;
```

In my mapping function I am mapping the habitId from my each habit-Observable to the habitId from my status-Observable.

[image]

Which is working fine. The problem is, I have **multiple objects in my status$-Oberservable** which I want to **map to one habitId of one habit$-Oberservable**. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), which returns a single item from an array.  You can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to return an array of all items that meet the specified condition:

```js
  map(([habits, statuses]) =>
    habits.map(habit => ({
      ...habit,
      statuses: statuses.filter(s => s.habitId === habit.habitId)
    })))
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. just use filter instead of find.
filter runs till the end of the array, and invokes its callback on every item; in contrast to find which stops after having found one.

```
connect(): Observable<any[]> {
this.userId = this.authService.userId;
this.habits$ = this.habitService.fetchAllById(this.userId);
this.status$ = this.statusService.fetchAll();
this.joined$ = forkJoin([this.habits$, this.status$]).pipe(
  map(([habits, statuses]) =>
    habits.map(habit => ({
      ...habit,
      status: statuses.filter(s => s.habitId === habit.habitId)
    })))
);
console.log(this.joined$);

return this.joined$;
```